# UICollectionView gap at top of view

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, xcode7, ios7.1

I am making interface changes to an existing app. I am using a UICollectionView to display a series of emoticons. The images show and are selectable, and even show in the previous view without issue, even after the changes I've made. Big one was the view was originally a UIViewController. I changed it to an actual UICollectionViewController
The problem I have is the HUGE space at the top of the view when it runs. It is not just 20 or even 50 pixels. It is more like 200-300 pixels!
The view is being created in storyboard, with a UICollectionView controller.
Cell size is 85 x 85. Min spacing is 10 and 10.
Section insets are 0, 10, 10, 10.
I have a transluscent nav bar on the view. (I've tried to Opaque, but no change).
Adjust scroll view insets is checked.
It is set up for a single section, with an array for items for the section. It will scroll and page without issue. It is just the top space!

Below is a screen capture of the collection view. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

[image]

Comment: can you please show your view hierarchy ? aslo look at the view debugger and see what is pushing the collection view down

Comment: What kind of layout is being used ? A custom one or a flow layout ?

Comment: Layout is Flow Scroll Direction is vertical. Nothing custom. No Accessories. View Mode is Top.

Comment: I've looked at the View Hierarchy and it is showing 3 rows of empty cells at the top of the view when it launches. At the moment, I can see no reason for 3 blank rows.

Comment: In looking at the images being displayed and using Logs, I have realized that the first nine emoticons are not displaying. And, the Cells are showing NULL. The array shows the correct count.

Comment: After digging some more, I discovered that after placing the images for the collection into Images.xcassets, that leading "0"s were being removed from the first 9 filenames! They did have hyphens before the number, which is part of the name... J4U_Emoji-01, etc. Changing the hyphen to underscore fixed the issue. All are now displaying! Thanks MrT for the hint about the view hierarchy! Didn't know about this new feature!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was as noted in the comment above... the filenames had been changed when I moved the images for the array into Images.xcassets. Previously, the filenames had a hyphen before the number. Replacing all of the files with filenames that contained underscores instead of hyphens kept the filenames from changing, which fixed the issue! Thanks for the hint about View Hierarchy MrT!